# imprimir informacion de array

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

estoy tratando de hacer una tarea de laravel y tengo un problema con los arrays.

Debo imprimir información de dos meses específicos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    $datos = [
    ['Marzo' => ['id' => 1, 'estado' => 'Pago']],
    ['Abril' => ['id' => 2, 'estado' => 'No Pago']],
];
```

Estoy atascado en la parte de imprimir el array con el foreach en el blade.

```
              @foreach($datos as $dato)

                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$dato->id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$dato->estado}} </td>
                                       
                                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

Error: **Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el error te dice que, estas esperando un "String", sin embargo, lo que obtiene es un "Array" y esto es correcto. Ya que cuando haces el `foreach` estas recorriendo el primer "nivel" de tu arreglo, sin embargo, aun debes generar otro arreglo para acceder a los arreglos que tienes, en este caso, `Marzo y Abril`,

Para solucionarlo es fácil, debes agregar otro `foreach` dentro de tu `foreach`, una vez que tengas eso, ahora si puedes acceder a la propiedad que necesitas en blade, algo asi:

```
$datos[
    ['Marzo' => ['id' => 1, 'estado' => 'Pago']],
    ['Abril' => ['id' => 2, 'estado' => 'No Pago']],
];

foreach($datos as $dato => $valor){
    foreach($valor as $propiedad){
       <td> {{$propiedad['id']}} </td>
       <td> {{$propiedad['estado']}} </td>
    }
}
```

Intenta de esta manera, a ver que te sale